# How can I use MarkerCluster among Layers in python folium?

Tags: python, folium

I'm trying to create a map with folium and python with different markers. There are some markers sharing location but belonging different layers. I want to cluster those markers and when I disable one layer, the markers of that layer are disabled too.

How can I use MarkerCluster property among layers in python folium?

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: Do you want one checkbox per cluster?

Comment: No. I want to group markers even if they belong to different layers.